# What is the best way to find out if 2 dates are in same month in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have 2 dates that are unix time stamps and I would have to figure out if the dates are in same month. For example if I have `1393624800 = 02 / 28 / 14` and `1391472000 = 2 / 4 / 2014`. I figured I could convert the unix time stamps to format like `28-02-2014` and extract the month, but I feel like its kinda dirty method. What is the best way to do this?

EDIT: Sry I forgot. Also have to make sure its the same year.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would suggest using the DateTime class

```
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date1->setTimestamp($timestamp1);

$date2 = new DateTime();
$date2->setTimestamp($timestamp2);

if ($date1->format('Y-m') === $date2->format('Y-m')) {
    // year and month match
}
```

I would highly suggest to anyone learning PHP to learn the DateTime and related classes. They are much more powerful than the basic date functions.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (date("F Y", $date1) == date("F Y", $date2))
```

see
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

that makes sure they are in the same month and year, otherwise do something like:

```
if (date("n", $date1) == date("n", $date2))
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably this:

```
$first = date("m", $timestamp);
$second = date("m", $timestamp2);

if($first == $second) {
   // they are in same month
}
else {
   // they aren't
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You can get month of  unix timestamp simply using php date function.

So $date1 = 1393624800;

& $date2 = 1391472000 ;

You can easily check if month are same or not using date('m')

**PHP CODE**

```
if(date('m', $date1) == date('m', $date2)){ //Action; }
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-01 00:00:00')); // == 1338534000
```

Which translates to:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time); // == 2012-06-01 00:00:00
```

Read the PHP manual on the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) functions.