# Checking to see of two DateTime objects refer to the same day

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to see whether two DateTimeImmutable objects refer to the same calendar day, and I can't figure out why the code below does not work. Code is PHP.

```
function isSameDay( $x, $y ){

        echo "<p>Comparing '" . $x->format('Y-m-d') . "' and '" . $y->format('Y-m-d'). "' returns";

        if( $x->format('Y-m-d') == $y->format('Y-m-d)') ){
                echo " true </p>";
                return true;
        }

        echo " false </p>";
        return false;
        
}
```

When testing, I'm getting the following output, where the top test case should be returning true:

```
Comparing '2021-09-06' and '2021-09-06' returns false

Comparing '2021-09-06' and '2021-10-29' returns false

Comparing '2021-09-06' and '2021-11-24' returns false

Comparing '2021-09-06' and '2021-11-26' returns false
```

My understanding is that DateTimeImmutable->format() returns a string, so the if statement is just a string comparison. In fact, the compare-as-strings approach seems to be one of the main approaches for comparing dates like this. For example, the comparison I use above is given as answers to several questions here:

[What is the best way to find out if 2 dates are in same month in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545899/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-out-if-2-dates-are-in-same-month-in-php)

[Check if two PHP datetime objects are set to the same date ( ignoring time )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328416/check-if-two-php-datetime-objects-are-set-to-the-same-date-ignoring-time/8328507)

Answer (score 1):

Sigh, nevermind. There's an extra parentheses in `$y->format('Y-m-d)')`